# EXCEPTION :Async operation timed out - When reading input stream in servlet

Tags: java, exception, servlets, inputstream

I got the exception `EXCEPTION  :Async operation timed out` when reading input stream in servlet.
Code for read input stream is :

```
        ServletInputStream rdata = request.getInputStream();
        int contentLength = request.getContentLength()!=-1?request.getContentLength():0;
        byte[] ar_byte = new byte[contentLength];
        rdata.read(ar_byte, 0, request.getContentLength());
        json_str =  new String(ar_byte, "UTF-8");
```

I got exception at line
`rdata.read(...`
 when my application is running in `WebSphere 6.1` but i didnt get when it is running in `Tomcat 6.0`

StackTrace for Exception is :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Async operation timed out
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:157)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPReadRequestContextImpl.read(TCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:109)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.fillABuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:4130)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readSingleBlock(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3374)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.impl.HttpServiceContextImpl.readBodyBuffer(HttpServiceContextImpl.java:3479)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.getRequestBodyBuffer(HttpInboundServiceContextImpl.java:1604)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.bufferIsGood(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:235)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCCByteBufferInputStream.read(WCCByteBufferInputStream.java:153)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.http.HttpInputStream.read(HttpInputStream.java:308)
at servlet.AppServlet.doPost(AppServlet.java:226)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1213)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:658)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:764)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:457)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:300)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:102)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
Caused by: com.ibm.io.async.AsyncTimeoutException(Async operation timed out, [Timeout, rc=0])
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.waitForCompletion(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:359)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.getByteCount(AsyncFuture.java:216)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:150)
... 30 more
```

Can any one give suggestion to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.